# Replace null with '-' in json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have null value in json response I want to replace all the occurance of 'null' with '-'.In reason and sub reason I want to displaying 'null'.need to replace it with '-'

```js
const response=[
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "customeraccounttype":"Existing Customer",
            "expectedclosuredate":"31-Jan-2020",
            "datecreated":"15-Jan-2020",
            "datemodified":"03-Apr-2020",
            "salesstagelastmodified":"03-Apr-2020",
            "reason":null,
            "sub_reason":null
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Akhil Pal",
            "customeraccounttype":"New Customer",
            "expectedclosuredate":"29-Nov-2019",
            "datecreated":"01-Aug-2019",
            "datemodified":"04-Apr-2020",
            "salesstagelastmodified":"04-Apr-2020",
            "reason":null,
            "sub_reason":null
         },
         {
            "UserName":"bala Shanmugam",
            "customeraccounttype":"New Customer",
            "expectedclosuredate":"30-Sep-2019",
            "datecreated":"01-Aug-2019",
            "datemodified":"05-Apr-2020",
            "salesstagelastmodified":"05-Apr-2020",
            "reason":null,
            "sub_reason":null
         }
      ];
      const mapped = response.map(r => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(r).map(([ key, val ]) =>
  [ key, val ?? "-" ])));
  console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the above code can replace null.but doesn't support in explorer and edge 12

```
const mapped = response.map(r => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(r).map(([ key, val ]) =>
  [ key, val ?? "-" ])));
```

https://caniuse.com/ I found  some browser doesn't suppot `??`

[image: browser compaibility]

Comment: and what's the question now?

Comment: So you're asking what to use instead of `??`? If so: `null === val ? "-" : val`

Comment: Alternatively, you could output/fetch it as required.

Comment: @yoshi can you please post ur answer

Comment: TBH if you're worried about using IE11 then you also shouldn't be using `=>`?  https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: And then `.map` doesn't work in "some browsers" (IE8...)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: And (I'll stop now) what about `const` https://caniuse.com/#search=const

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceNull(value) {
 response.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (o[k] === null) {
            o[k] = value;
        }
    });
});
}



replaceNull("-");

console.log(response);
```